# SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near ")": syntax error

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

I have created a data table with sqflite. But it showed me a syntax error. Can you tell me please where is the syntax error here?

```
Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnfid VARCHAR,
            $columnfname TEXT,
          )
          ''');
  }
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near ")": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE fid_table (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            fid VARCHAR,
            fname TEXT,
          )) sql '          CREATE TABLE fid_table (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            fid VARCHAR,
            fname TEXT,
          )
          ' args []})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is with the trailing comma (,) of the SQL, i.e after the last **TEXT**.

Instead of

```
await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE $table (
        $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        $columnfid VARCHAR,
        $columnfname TEXT,
      )
      ''');
```

try

```
wait db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE $table (
        $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        $columnfid VARCHAR,
        $columnfname TEXT
      )
      ''');
```

Also, the extra quotes are not required as well. So, you could write this as well.

```
wait db.execute('
      CREATE TABLE $table (
        $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        $columnfid VARCHAR,
        $columnfname TEXT
      )
      ');
```